# Каков смысл связки «вполне себе»?

Tags: словосочетания

И следом — второй вопрос: что отличает просто ***вполне*** от ***вполне себе***?

Второе употребляется, пожалуй, активней, и тому много (и разных) примеров здесь, на РЯбете. ***Вполне из себя***, ***полно тебе*** принимаются, а с пониманием ***вполне себе*** совсем туго, на нуле.

И последнее. Не следовало бы замыкать запятыми это словосочетание затем, что бы пауза предотвращала его распространение на последующие слова, и особенно глаголы: «себе подчеркивает, себе улыбается».

Answer (score 2):

ВПОЛНЕ, нареч. Совершенно, полностью, в полной мере. В. доволен. В. готов. В. определённый ответ. В. достаточно.

Как мне кажется, выражение "вполне себе" ― разговорное, оценочное, причем оценка трактуется не как объективная, а как заданная в каком-то внутренне ограниченном  рассмотрении и понимании вопроса, например:

Я комментирую собственные записи, которые вполне себе милые.

Это вполне себе интересная трилогию о жестком охотнике на вампиров.

Пляжи в Крыму стали вполне себе турецкие.

Домашнее образование ― вполне себе вариант для детей, не умеющих за себя постоять и всю оставшуюся жизнь собирающихся прятаться от сурового мира, кому есть где прятаться.

Мама есть, вполне себе интеллигентная мама. И т. д.

Comment: вполне себе - это не просто раговорное, это либо ироническое (наподобие т.н. эрратива), либо совсем уже просторечное.

Comment: А в чем здесь  ирония?  Это скрытая насмешка,  или противоположный смысл, или еще что-то из другой области?  И для просторечия здесь вроде бы нет явных оттенков упрощения, сниженности, грубоватости. Да и область применения выражения очень разнообразная.

Comment: А в чем ирония в "две большие разницы"? "Говорить за Одессу"? "Не делай маме нервы"? Это только из одесского набора. Кстати, есть подозрение, что "вполне себе" тоже одессизм.

Comment: «Я комментирую собственные записи, которые вполне себе милые.» Спасибо за прелестный этот шедевр. Большую мерзость выдумать невозможно: себе милые.

Answer (score 1):

Время от времени в языке появляются вот такие вот уродцы. Вроде вот этого вот "вполне себе". Любое объяснение смысла этой связки - пустое словоблудие. Слово "вполне" самодостаточно, информативно, описательно и закончено. И совершенно не нуждается в приклеивании сзади этого нелепого довесочка. 
Но у нас всегда так. Один дурак брякнет, и толпы попугаев разнесут. Вспомните как совсем недавно с ума можно было сойти от постоянно слышимого "как бы". Но, вроде бы переболели в основном. Я сам - не образец носителя русского литературного...Но некоторые глупости или пакости, вроде "толерантности" или пресловутого "кушать" просто вгоняют в уныние. Равно как и вот эта, модная нынче и противная в своей расхожести, связочка "вполне себе". Подозреваю, что просто нравится как звучит. Чистая фонетика. Хотя.... И тут не поддержу. Но, - это уже вкусовщина.

Comment: *Но некоторые глупости или пакости, вроде "толерантности" или пресловутого "кушать" просто вгоняют в уныние.* - не по сути. Мы тут только об одном обороте "вполне себе". Тут даже аналогии нет, ибо "кушать" и "толерантность" - вполне себе слова, а не глупости. И вообще старайтесь отвечать конкретно, а не изливать душу на тему "как все плохо стало". Здесь не болталочный форум, а  сервис вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Понять смысл очевидного уродца и выразить словами (лучше на бумаге), а не жестами, нужно, чтобы с ним покончить.

Answer (score 0):

- Оборот "вполне себе" появился в русской речи в начале 2000-х по данным Национального корпуса русского языка, он трактуется как личностная оценка той, или иной ситуации, окружения, предмета и т.д.
- если систематизировать все степени личностной оценки, то "вполне себе" занимает вершину этого списка, например такие выражения как:
- "так себе" расценивают как нечто посредственное,
- "ничего себе/так"-сносно, либо неплохо,
- "вполне себе"- в полной мере/совершенно.

Comment: С оценочным «ничего себе» как «сносно» понятно. А с восклицанием (от испуга) или крайним удивлением оно разве не выпадает из этой тройки? И потом: «вполне» разве не то же самое, что — в полной мере / совершенно? Именно в этом вопрос: в чём разница.

Answer (score -1):

Мне просто режет ухо это "ВПОЛНЕ СЕБЕ"! Зачем портить и засорять русский язык? Какое-то дурацкое словосочетание.
Хватит коверкать могучий и неповторимый русский язык. Как до сих пор не делают разницы, применяя глаголы *одеть-надеть*. Даже на "Модном приговоре" ведущие(Васильев и Хромченко) очень долго говорили: "Оденьте это платье!" Кошмар! А ведь так просто знать простое правило: глаголу "надеть" антоним — "снять"; глаголу "одеть" антоним — "раздеть"! Ведь не скажешь: разденьте это платье, туфли, жакет и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, но надо бы всё-таки по теме. Лучше behemothus (от 13 июн '16 в 10:12) не скажешь: « И вообще старайтесь отвечать конкретно, а не изливать душу на тему "как все плохо стало". Здесь не болталочный форум, а сервис вопросов и ответов».